# Mysql last hour data

Tags: mysql, time

I tried several ways I found here, but it spits out more than the last hour.

The table has a field t_timestamp with data like:

```
2018-06-29 00:00:02
2018-06-29 00:10:01
2018-06-29 00:20:02
2018-06-29 00:30:01
2018-06-29 00:40:02
2018-06-29 00:50:01
2018-06-29 01:00:02
2018-06-29 01:10:01
2018-06-29 01:20:02
2018-06-29 01:30:01
2018-06-29 01:40:02
2018-06-29 01:50:01
```

It is now 2018-06-29 01:55:04

Above was created although I used something like:

```
WHERE t_timestamp >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
WHERE (now() - t_timestamp)<360000
....
```

Where is my thinking error?

------ edited ------
I think the problem is in the field of t_timestamp, at the time it was collected. As longer the day gets, as more data I get from THAT day only, actually all from today.

I got the time field as ($tickers[$symbol1]['datetime']): 
"2018-06-29T00:00:02.732"

I used to format it:

```
    $a = explode('T',$tickers[$symbol1]['datetime']);
    $b = explode(".",$a[1]);
    $t_timestamp = $a[0] . " " . $b[0];
```

Could it be, that this is causing the trouble?

Comment: What is your expected output here?  Given a current hour of `01:55:04`, how far back do you need to go?

Comment: Your first `WHERE` clause works for me.

Answer (score 2):

Demo :http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f5e2c3/8/0

Solution:

```
create table mytime(times timestamp);

insert into mytime values('2018-06-29 00:00:02');
insert into mytime values('2018-06-29 00:10:01');
insert into mytime values('2018-06-29 00:20:02');
insert into mytime values('2018-06-29 00:30:01');
insert into mytime values('2018-06-29 00:40:02');
insert into mytime values('2018-06-29 00:50:01');

insert into mytime values('2018-06-29 01:00:02');
insert into mytime values('2018-06-29 01:10:01');
insert into mytime values('2018-06-29 01:20:02');
insert into mytime values('2018-06-29 01:30:01');
insert into mytime values('2018-06-29 01:40:02');
insert into mytime values('2018-06-29 01:50:01');


-- time from given time
select *
from  mytime
where times >= DATE_SUB('2018-06-29 01:50:10',INTERVAL 1 HOUR); 

-- time from now time
select *
from  mytime
where times >= DATE_SUB(now(),INTERVAL 1 HOUR);
```

Comment: Looks so simple, but still I cannot get it to work! SELECT * FROM tickers WHERE t_timestamp >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 HOUR) ORDER BY t_timestamp;   brings nothing out. Even your code gives me wrong data, if I have now 02:30:00, I still get all values with the hour 01:xx:xx.

Comment: use ORDER BY t_timestamp ASC OR use ORDER BY t_timestamp DESC

Comment: I am frustrated! SELECT * FROM tickers WHERE  (now() - t_timestamp)<3600000 ORDER BY t_timestamp; Regardless if ASC or DESC brings me 102 records, from 01:50:00 till 12:50:00 
SELECT * tickers WHERE t_timestamp >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 HOUR) ORDER BY t_timestamp; brings no records at all!!! It is now here 14:51